# unable to use ajaxcalender control with master page

Tags: asp.net

I have created one simple aspx page using ajax calnder control-- page working fine
but i am creating a user control with ajax calender control and trying to use it with master page its not workng -- after click on button no popup apperring and page got post back,

Comment: Can you post some code? Sounds like you may be loading this usercontrol dynamically but I can't be sure for the information you've given.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it works in asp.net, but at MVC to enable calendar, simply add anywhere on the View

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server" >
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptLocalization="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>        
</form>
```

HTH.